# What is wrong with the energy of a particle, of which the mass increase with time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, energy-conservation

Let a particle move in space with constant velocity $v$. Its mass is directly proportional to time: $m=\mu t$, where $\mu$ is a constant with dimension kg $\text{s}^{-1}$. A single force acts on the particle so that it can maintain its constant velocity $v$. No other forces act on the particle.

This is not strange at all: just imagine you are pushing a trolley, and people around you continuously throw stationary things into the trolley. That's how it gains mass.

Now here is the problem:

The particle has no potential energy. Let $E$ denote the total energy inside the system, then $E$ is also the total kinetic energy. On one hand, we have

$$
dE=d(\frac{1}{2}mv^2)=d(\frac{1}{2}\mu v^2t)=\frac{1}{2}\mu v^2dt.
$$

On the other hand, we have
$$
dE=Fdx=\frac{dp}{dt}dx=vdp=vd(\mu t v)=\mu v^2dt,
$$
which differs for the first expression by a factor of $2$. What's wrong? Why energy disappears?

Comment: Isn’t it a odd question? **”Let a particle ***move in space*** with constant velocity ... A single force acts on the particle so that it can maintain its constant velocity ”**   In free space the particle will accelerate in the described case?     **”Its mass is directly proportional to time: =.”**  Where does the part get its mass from?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler Not strange at all: just imagine you are pushing a trolley, and people around you continuously throw stationary things into the trolley. That's how it gains mass.

Comment: Thrown things are not stationary.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thrown things are stationary in the direction of motion of trolley, because they move perpendicular to each other.

Comment: In that case, you aren't just adding mass, you're also adding kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2):

The first expression is correct. The second equation does not apply as no work is done. You are adding mass that already moves at the same speed $v$. The work done to *get* that mass at $v$ is not included in your kinetic energy expression.

Comment: So when does my second equation apply?