# A conveyor belt with changing mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

There appears to be another question about conveyor belt on this site; however, that question just asks for a correct expression. I actually have asked much more than that question. I provided an additional formula that I derived and asked whether it is correct. This is not included in that question.

A conveyor belt moves at constant velocity $v$. At $t=0$, sand starts to be dropped onto the belt at the rate $\mu \text{kg/s}$. The mass of sand on the belt is, therefore, $m=\mu t$. **Please ignore resistive forces in this question.**

**NB** Sand has **zero** velocity in the direction of the belt's motion **before** it is dropped onto the belt. Sand does NOT have any kinetic energy before it reaches the belt, and when it reaches the belt, it moves with the belt, with velocity $v$: they are "attached" to each other.

The belt continues to move with constant velocity $v$ throughout.

Now, the problem I am trying to solve is:

> What is the **additional** power needed to keep the speed of conveyor belt constant, *after sand starts to drop*?

I tried to work it out in two ways, but got different results.

Method 1:
$$
P=\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{d (\frac{1}{2} mv^2)}{dt}=\frac{d (\frac{1}{2} \mu v^2 t)}{dt}=\frac{1}{2} \mu v^2.
$$

Method 2:
$$
P=\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{Fdx}{dt}=Fv=v\frac{dp}{dt}=v\frac{d(mv)}{dt}= v^2\frac{dm}{dt}+mv\frac{dv}{dt}=\mu v^2.
$$

**I have no idea which is right**: intuitively, $\frac{1}{2} mv^2$ is the total kinetic energy gained by the sand. Dividing this by $t$ gives the average power $\frac{1}{2} \mu v^2$. So this seems to be the correct value.

However, the mark scheme says the answer is $\mu v^2$. My second method also seems more reliable, in that it just uses the *definition* of momentum and force.

I doubt that the formula $E=(1/2) mv^2$ may not be correct in this situation:
$$
dE=Fdx=vdp=\frac{1}{2m}2p dp=\frac{1}{2m}d(p^2),
$$
which is not the same as $E=(1/2) mv^2$, because $m$ is not constant. However, the expression $\frac{1}{2m}d(p^2)$ looks very strange and counterintuitive. (Why $m$ is not differentiated?!)

**Which of the above are correct and which are wrong?**

Can anyone explain intuitively where the factor of $1/2$ comes from?

**Why the statement** "intuitively, $\frac{1}{2} mv^2$ is the total kinetic energy gained by the sand. Dividing this by $t$ gives the average power $\frac{1}{2} \mu v^2$" is **incorrect?**

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/477101/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes. This is an apparently similar, but essentially very different question.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/381273/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Approaches to Sand on a Conveyor Belt](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/381273/)

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs There appears to be another question about conveyor belt on this site; however, that question just asks for a correct expression. I actually have asked much more than that question. I provided an additional formula that I derived and asked whether it is correct. This is not included in that question.

Comment: See also e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451974/ and the links therein. Friction is doing work that is unaccounted for in your $E = 0.5mv^2$ expression.